# Law regarding toilets use in The Netherlands

Tags: netherlands, sex-discrimination

Today my manager sent an email to our department regarding the toilet use; they said that it is not allowed to use the ladies' room as a man, by law, and vice versa.

That got me curious.

Note that I work for a fairly large company which is not in the catering industry.

My questions:

- Is is prohibited for a man to *use* the ladies' room?
- Is there any other law saying something about the *construction* or *possession* of such toilets, such as the *Arbeidsomstandighedenbesluit* or something?
- Are there perhaps special laws for the catering industry regarding this affair?

Comment: it might be considered sexual harrassment to use the ladies room as a gentleman. The reverse also is true usually.

Comment: @Trish But it may get complicated if we take people into consideration which don't identify as either, leaving them no room(!) to go to the toilet.

Comment: Indeed, which is a problem lawmakers are looking to deal with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, [article 3.24 of the *Arbeidsomstandighedenbesluit*](https://wetten.overheid.nl/BWBR0008498/2022-01-01/#Hoofdstuk3_Afdeling1_Paragraaf5_Artikel3.24):

> Toiletten en wastafels
>
> 1. In een bedrijf of inrichting zijn in de nabijheid van de ruimten waar de werknemers hun werkzaamheden verrichten een voldoende aantal toiletten aanwezig.
> 2. In of in de onmiddellijke nabijheid van de ruimten waarin de toiletten zich bevinden zijn voldoende wastafels.
> 3. De toiletten of het gebruik van de toiletten zijn naar seksen gescheiden.

My translation (intentionally less idiomatic than it might be in order to parallel the Dutch word order):

> Toilets and lavatories
>
> 1. In a business or facility there are in the vicinity of the areas where the workers perform their work a sufficient number of toilets present.
> 2. In, or in the immediate vicinity of, the areas where the toilets are, there are sufficient lavatories.
> 3. The toilets or the use of the toilets are segregated by sex.

It's a very long law, so I haven't read it all, but it doesn't seem to impose a penalty on people who disregard the sex segregation of the toilets.  I suspect that it imposes a responsibility on the employer to enforce the segregation, and presumably a penalty could be imposed on the employer for failing to do so.  I do not know what mechanisms would be available to the employer to penalize an employee who uses the wrong toilet.

I don't know anything about the catering industry, and I cannot infer why you ask about it specifically.  If you're asking about toilets provided by such businesses for their *customers,* however, I suspect it's likely to be governed by another law.  (I further suspect that sex-segregated toilets for customers are optional in at least some circumstances, since small bars and restaurants often have only one toilet.)

Comment: Which leaves the question whether an employer needs to _provide_ sex-segregated toilets, or that they need to _enforce_ its sex-segregated use.